# Why Java NMT commited memory could be much less then RSS? (if there is no swap)

Tags: java, memory

I am searching for a memory leak in native memory, while the RSS memory is always increasing, the total NMT committed memory is always +- on the same level.

At the start of the process (after a few minutes after cold boot) the RSS and NMT are equal ~ 3,6GB.

But after a day the RSS of the java process is 6GB, while the total committed memory shown by NMT is 3,7GB.

Important to say, that we are tracking the amount of page major faults, and it is always zero, that's why I am expecting that the used memory is always resident, so the committed and RSS memory should be equal.

I have already checked two hypothesis:

- I have heard about directly mapped files leak, that could not be tracked by NMT, but after profiling with async-profiler the call of the fileChannel.map a got nothing
- Also there is only one JNI library, but I am 99% sure that there is no leak here

Are there more possible situations, when the memory could not be tracked by NMT?

Comment: I would suggest this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c755fFv1Rnk He explains parts of the JVM which consume memory, only one of which is the heap. He works through some examples of how to diagnose issues.

Comment: Yes, I saw this video, from that video I put forward that two hypothesis, but they ware not confirmed

Comment: @Di Sarra George, I am facing the same issue. were you able to make any progress.